# Windows 8 constantly reverting changes (flash uninstalled)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, flash, windows-update

I uninstalled flash when I restored my machine. I also uninstalled IE from the system list. Now in Windows update there is an update for flash, and I believe the OS is trying to install it on every micro patch, thus resulting in a "reverting changes" screen that takes about 30 minutes to bypass.

Was not really an issue before but now with the new update policy I guess it's quite frequent.

How can I disable this patch?

Answer (score 0):

Source [How to Hide or Restore Hidden Windows Updates in Windows 7 and Windows 8](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/24376-windows-update-hide-restore-hidden-updates.html):

> This tutorial will show you how to either hide or unhide Windows
>   Updates to have them listed or not listed as available to install
>   again in Windows 7 and Windows 8.
>
> **To Hide a Windows Update**
>
> 1. Open the Control Panel (icons view), and click/tap on the Windows Update icon.
> 2. After Windows Updates or you check for updates, click/tap on the .....update(s) is available link.
> 3. Right click or press and hold on a listed Windows Update that you want to hide, then click/tap on Hide Update.
> 4. If prompted by UAC, then click/tap on Yes or enter the administrator's password.
> 5. You will now notice that the now hidden Windows Update is grayed out. Repeat steps 3 and 4 to hide another Windows Update. When
>      done, click/tap on OK.

The above link includes screenshots for each of the steps.